# Using MATLAB Data Acquisition toolbox and trying to calibrate a signal in a while loop

Tags: matlab, calibration, data-acquisition

collecting Live data from a simulated NI-6001 which has 8 channels. I have got to the point where I can display multiple plots on the liveaxes but, It is only showing the calibrated signal on the plots when I only use one of the slopes & intercepts. As soon as I try to use multiple slopes and intercepts it no longer works.

Code for calibration of the multiple channels. The main body of code that I think is where the problem is is here

```
%if the calibration switch is turned on use the slopes and
% intercepts read in above
if app.calibrate == true
               %app.indices is a private property that tracks the selected channels in the UI of the app 
              
 while i < numel(app.indices)

                i = i + 1;

                data(:,i) = data(:,i)*slope(:,i)+intercepts(:,i);
               
               end 
             
            
           % if the calibration switch is turned off then just display data as Voltage 
           elseif app.calibrate == false

             data = data*1 + 0;
           
           end
```

Code used for data displayed on the graph

```
buffersize = round(app.DAQ.Rate * app.TimewindowEditField.Value) + 1;
app.TimestampsFIFOBuffer = storeDataInFIFO(app, app.TimestampsFIFOBuffer, buffersize, timestamps);

 app.DataFIFOBufferch1 = storeDataInFIFO(app, app.DataFIFOBufferch1, buffersize, data(:,app.indices));

 plot(app.LiveAxes, app.TimestampsFIFOBuffer, app.DataFIFOBufferch1)
```

I read in the slopes and intercepts calculated in the workspace and read it in using `evalin`.

When the calibrate switch is in noting appears on the graph vs when it is off

[uncalibrateddata[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpKSr.png)

[calibrateddata[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG9yX.png)

Comment: realized that I needed to use a for loop 'for i = 1:max(app.indices)   
                     data(:,i) = data(:,i)*app.sl(:,i)+app.int(:,i);   
                end' assuming the user selects channels from most to least